# Why am I getting this CloudFormation error?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-application-load-balancer

I am having a problem with creating a ALB listener rule using cloudformation. I have whittled it down to this minimal example.

The error message is really unhelpful.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: CloudFormation template for creating a listener

Resources:
  TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: "dummy-target-group-deleteme"
      Port: 8080
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: vpc-00000000000000000

  ListenerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      Actions:
        - Type: forward
          ForwardConfig:
            TargetGroups:
              - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
                Weight: 1
      Conditions:
        - Field: http-header
          HostHeaderConfig:
            Values:
              - "deleteme.example.com"
      ListenerArn: "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:account_id:listener/app/hosting/.../..."
      Priority: 3000
```

The error in cloudformation is as follows:

Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule Validation exception" (RequestToken: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

Comment: A listener cannot have multiple rules with the same priority. Just verifying that this isn't the case in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
Conditions:
        - Field: http-header
          HostHeaderConfig:
```

should be

```
Conditions:
        - Field: http-header
          HttpHeaderConfig:
```

example:

```
ListenerRule1:
Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule'
Properties:
  Actions:
    - Type: forward
      TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup1
  Conditions:
    - Field: http-header
      HttpHeaderConfig:
        HttpHeaderName: User-Agent
        Values:
          - Mozilla
```

This is a good reference: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudformation-user-guide/blob/main/doc_source/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule.md

Comment: Thanks for this.

I've been trying this since you suggested it but there are a few mistakes in your answer. I tried to edit it but couldn't. Please see if you can make the changes:

http-header -> host-header

You can then make the example relevant by changing 'Field: ...' and the next config line like your suggested.

HttpHeaderName line needs to be removed.

Mozilla needs to be changed to a domain name.

This also won't work without a Priority and ListenerArn.

Once one of us is able to make the changes I'll accept the answer.